# Properly render accent characters coming from API

Tags: javascript, angular8

I am receiving a description from an API (exactly copied from chrome network tab)

```
{
   description: "V\u00E1ci \u00DAt"
}
```

And displaying it through html template like below

```
<p [innerHTML]="res.description"></p>
```

The problem is it's priting it as it is.

```
V\u00E1ci \u00DAt
```

whereas I am expecting it to be

```
Váci Út
```

One weird thing I found while debugging in redux store, it's saved as below with double backward slash (exactly copied from redux tab from chrome dev tool)

```
V\\u00E1ci \\u00DAt
```

I have tried replacing double slash to single, but that also doesn't change anything.

But when I copy the value from chrome tab and store in some dummy variable and then display it, it works perfectly. You can try coping the text from this question and paste in chrome console, it will print perfectly. But does not work when reading from API call.

Please someone help me finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Edited based on OP's comment**

To be able to display accented characters correctly on the HTML Template of your Component you will need to do something like this:

- Use the `string.prototype.normalize( )` function on the `res.description` before printing it out:

`<p [innerHTML]="res.description.normalize('NFC')"></p>`

Can you please try the above HTML template code and let me know if it solves your problem?

---

---

**Original Answer:**

You can use the `String.prototype.normalize( )` function in order to normalize the description string before displaying it on the component template file.

String.prototype.normalize( ) is an ES2015 function, but because you are using Angular 8 the default `polyfill.ts` can take care of polyfilling the ES2015 syntax for you.

Below is an example on how you can use the `String.prototype.normalize( )` function. You can check out the documentation here: [String.prototype.normalize MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize)

```js
const accentedText = 'V\u00E1ci \u00DAt';
//'NFC' is a normalization form which stands for Canonical Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition.
const normalizedText = accentedText.normalize('NFC');
document.querySelector('.accent').textContent = normalizedText;
```

```css
/*Only adding the below CSS and animations for fun, please ignore it, I just like good design.*/
.accent-container{
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
max-width: 30%;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
background-image:linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(45, 52, 54,.8), rgba(45, 52, 54,1.0));
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

.accent{
color: #fff;
font-family: 'Robot', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
}

.accent-container:hover{
transform: translateY(-3px);
box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.accent-container:active{
transform: translateY(0);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="accent-container">
<p class="accent"></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ans Link, but it doesn't help in my case. Surely will use your button though :P

Comment: Oh, why doesn't it work though? From my understanding you want to be able to display accented characters correctly on the HTML Template of your Component, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please try this and let me know if it helps to solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, by the way, you actually not require normalization to just display the text. If you just copy above string and feed it to html, it will work, but not working when same text is coming from API